# Устранить ошибку текстовой даты с 2х значным годом

Tags: excel

В B2 формула СУММЕСЛИ (формулы я вставил текстом ниже), она берет данные из F, в F ВПР берет данные из K. 
Почему-то эксель считает данные в K "текстовая дата с 2-значным годом" и из-за этого итоговая формула почему-то ломается, добавляя в СУММЕСЛИ значения, например 1.20,хотя критерий стоит только 1.1
Как-то можно это победить? Отформатировать исходные данные или дополнить формулу?

[image: пример]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`СУММЕСЛИ` "умная", она сама умеет преобразовывать данные (даже когда это не требуется). (Это касается условия, данные диапазонов функция не меняет)

1.1 - это в числовом выражении дата - 1 января, 1.2 - 1 февраля или 2 января (зависит от настроек).  Избежать преобразования в `СУММЕСЛИ` не получится. Можно изменить данные (чего-нибудь добавить (1.2q) или заменить точку на какую-нибудь закоряку), но зачем так извращаться?

Применим другую функцию:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(--(F2:F6=A2);G2:G6)
```

Comment: Жаль, хочется попроще формулы конечно иметь) А для чего "--" в формуле? Спасибо

Comment: Да ну, одна из простейших. Вы еще сложных формул, видимо, не видели :) Кстати, почитайте о закреплениях ссылок (относительные, абсолютные ссылки). В Ваших формулах (В ВПР точно)  нужно закреплять диапазоны.

Comment: Не знаю, не знаю, мне не понятно как она работает)) Да это понятно, это я пример сделал, оригинал это куча листов и данных)

Comment: Двойное отрицание в данном случае преобразовывает логические выражения получаемого массива в числовые значения (`СУММПРОИЗВ` не понимает логических `ЛОЖЬ`, `ИСТИНА`). А сама функция работе так: поэлементно (построчно) перемножает значения, потом суммирует результаты. При перемножении получаем: где `ЛОЖЬ` - 0*число=0, где `ИСТИНА` - 1*число=число. Вот и весь секрет. Почти то же, что и `СУММЕСЛИ` (там если `ЛОЖЬ`, то значение игнорируется)

Comment: Так понятнее, главное не забывать что за двойное отрицание у меня тут такое) спасибо

Comment: А суммпроизв на весь столбец делать это нормально?

Comment: Нет, ненормально. Растягивайте на диапазон данных. Можно с запасом, но весь столбец не стоит грузить, будет тормозить. А двойное отрицание можно заменить математической операцией (условие*1, условие+0), но это медленнее работает